# How to select specific xml node in R if the same node name occurs multiple times?

Tags: r, xml, tree

I'm trying to check if specific nodes exist within xml files. I'm dealing with unstructured data, so certain nodes don't appear in every xml file, and sometimes multiple occurrences of the same node name can appear, except they will be children to other nodes.

Below is a sample xml file similar to what I am working with. As you can see, the node NM appears twice. However, I only want the first value, and not the other value that occurs. Is there a way to specify that I only want the first occurrence of NM to be retrieved? Either that or I don't want want the NM value if it is a child of another node, i.e. the one that is a child of StagesStage.

I'm using the package XML, and here is the code I have so far that retrieves the node details.

XML:

```
<Product>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NM>Product Name</NM>
    <DN>Product Description</DN>
    <SalesStage>
        <NM>Sales Stage Name</NM>
    </SalesStage>
</Product>
```

R Code:

```
doc = xmlInternalTreeParse("File.xml")

NM_Node = xpathApply(doc, "//NM")
print(NM_Node)

[[1]]
<NM>Product Name</NM> 

[[2]]
<NM>Sales Stage Name</NM> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

So in short, I only want to retrieve the value "Product Name", and not "Sales Stage Name". Is there anyway I can achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never played with R but xPath is xPath so here it goes. Have you tried:

```
NM_Node = xpathApply(doc, "//Product/NM")
```

This should only give you NM nodes that have a parent named Product, regardless of where this is in the file.

Here's a complete example:

```
text <- "<Product>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NM>Product Name</NM>
    <DN>Product Description</DN>
    <SalesStage>
        <NM>Sales Stage Name</NM>
    </SalesStage>
</Product>"

library(XML)

doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(text)

xpathApply(doc, "//Product/NM", xmlValue)
## [[1]]
## [1] "Product Name"

xpathSApply(doc, "//Product/NM", xmlValue)
## [1] "Product Name"
```

You can see the difference in what the two different XML `*apply` statements do. One returns a list, the other returns a character vector.

Comment: `xpathSapply()` as well (vs `xpathApply()`) if the OP just wants a character vector back. Solid code, though, for someone who has never worked with R before.

Comment: @Alex A You know I could have sworn I already tried that, but low and behold it works! Thanks a lot man! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @hrbrmstr What's the difference between`xpathSapply()` and `xpathApply()`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternately with `xml2`:

```
text <- "<Product>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NM>Product Name</NM>
    <DN>Product Description</DN>
    <SalesStage>
        <NM>Sales Stage Name</NM>
    </SalesStage>
</Product>"

library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml(text)
xml_find_all(doc, "//Product/NM") %>% xml_text()
```